# Android app - Multiply and divide multiple user entered values

Tags: java, android

First, I must admit I'm new to android programming. I want to create an app that has a total of 6 boxes to enter numbers. I want the first number (given by user in box 1) to be divided by the numbers in the other respective boxes. These numbers will always be multiplied by 100 in order to get their percentage. I also want all the results to show in a toast with one button click that shows all the results.

Example of numbers user could enter in editText:

1. Number of People = 50
2. 210(50/210*100) = 23.80
3. 20 (50/20*100)= 250
4. 15 (50/15*100) = 333.33
5. 10 (50/10*100) = 500
6. 25 (50/25*100) = 200

Here's the code I have so far in Main Activity.Java  - I'm having trouble figuring out how I can add more values that I can use to divide by the first number.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    float number = Float.parseFloat(edtN.getText().toString());
    float number2 = Float.parseFloat(edtN2.getText().toString());
    float div = number / number2;
    float total = div * 100;
    tv.setText(Float.toString(total));
```

Thank you in advance for help with this.

Comment: Do you want the complete code?

Comment: I wouldn't require the xml but the main class would be helpful

Comment: Show your own effort and code trying to solve the problem (as properly formatted text in the question). If you get stuck at a specific issue, you can ask here.

Comment: @MichaelButscher thanks for the advice. I added a snippet of my code and appreciate any help

Comment: You can e.g. create an array with all the `EditText` objects (or maybe all except the first one) and one for the output `TextView` objects and process all with a for-loop.